# Ilias SOAP Constructor error on login

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, ilias

I'm testing the [Ilias](https://www.ilias.de) Soap interface. And I have a problem with the login function.

```php
<?php
include_once ("./nusoap/nusoap.php");
$client = new nusoap_client("https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8'; //that is a not working solution from stackoverflow

if ($err = $client->getError()) 
{
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
}

$valid = $client->call('login',
        array('client' => "ILIAS",
            'password' => "pw",
            'username' => "root"));

if ($err = $client->getError()) 
{
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
}

print_r($client);
?>
```

I get this error:

> Constructor error
>   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : Extra content at the end of the document

And here is the printed object:

```
nusoap_client Object ( 
    [username] => 
    [password] => 
    [authtype] => 
    [certRequest] => Array ( ) 
    [requestHeaders] => 
    [responseHeaders] => 
    [responseHeader] =>
    [document] => WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" 
    [endpoint] => https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl 
    [forceEndpoint] => 
    [proxyhost] => 
    [proxyport] => 
    [proxyusername] => 
    [proxypassword] => 
    [portName] => 
    [xml_encoding] => UTF-8 
    [http_encoding] => 
    [timeout] => 0 
    [response_timeout] => 30 
    [endpointType] => soap 
    [persistentConnection] => 
    [defaultRpcParams] => 
    [request] => POST /ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl HTTP/1.0 Host: localhost User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123) Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 SOAPAction: "" Content-Length: 591 ILIASpwroot 
    [response] => HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 07:33:55 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.31 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31 Content-Length: 462 Connection: close Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" 
    [responseData] => WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" 
    [cookies] => Array ( ) 
    [decode_utf8] => 1 
    [operations] => Array ( ) 
    [curl_options] => Array ( ) 
    [bindingType] => [use_curl] => 
    [fault] => 1 
    [faultcode] => WSDL [faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" 
    [faultdetail] => 
    [title] => NuSOAP 
    [version] => 0.9.5 
    [revision] => $Revision: 1.123 $ 
    [error_str] => WSDL: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" 
    [debug_str] => 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728354 nusoap_client: ctor wsdl= timeout=0 response_timeout=30 endpoint=string(55) "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl" 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728407 nusoap_client: instantiate SOAP with endpoint at https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728430 nusoap_client: call: operation=login, namespace=http://tempuri.org, soapAction=, rpcParams=, style=rpc, use=encoded, endpointType=soap params=array(3) { ["client"]=> string(5) "ILIAS" ["password"]=> string(2) "pw" ["username"]=> string(4) "root" } headers=bool(false) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728456 nusoap_client: serializing param array for operation login 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728467 nusoap_client: in serialize_val: name=client, type=, name_ns=, type_ns=, use=encoded, soapval= value=string(5) "ILIAS" attributes=bool(false) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728484 nusoap_client: serialize_val: serialize string 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728498 nusoap_client: serialize_val returning ILIAS 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728507 nusoap_client: in serialize_val: name=password, type=, name_ns=, type_ns=, use=encoded, soapval= value=string(2) "pw" attributes=bool(false) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728518 nusoap_client: serialize_val: serialize string 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728528 nusoap_client: serialize_val returning pw 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728536 nusoap_client: in serialize_val: name=username, type=, name_ns=, type_ns=, use=encoded, soapval= value=string(4) "root" attributes=bool(false) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728546 nusoap_client: serialize_val: serialize string 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728555 nusoap_client: serialize_val returning root 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728563 nusoap_client: wrapping RPC request with encoded method element 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728574 nusoap_client: In serializeEnvelope length=199 body (max 1000 characters)=ILIASpwroot style=rpc use=encoded encodingStyle=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728583 nusoap_client: headers: bool(false) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728590 nusoap_client: namespaces: array(0) { } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728607 nusoap_client: endpoint=https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl, soapAction=, namespace=http://tempuri.org, style=rpc, use=encoded, encodingStyle=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728614 nusoap_client: SOAP message length=591 contents (max 1000 bytes)=ILIASpwroot 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728633 nusoap_client: transporting via HTTP 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728745 nusoap_client: sending message, length=591 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728648 soap_transport_http: ctor url=https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl use_curl= curl_options: array(0) { } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728665 soap_transport_http: parsed URL scheme = https 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728673 soap_transport_http: parsed URL host = localhost 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728679 soap_transport_http: parsed URL path = /ilias/webservice/soap/server.php 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728685 soap_transport_http: parsed URL query = wsdl 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728703 soap_transport_http: set header Host: localhost 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728720 soap_transport_http: set header User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728729 soap_transport_http: set header Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728737 soap_transport_http: set header SOAPAction: "" 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728758 soap_transport_http: entered send() with data of length: 591 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728769 soap_transport_http: connect connection_timeout 0, response_timeout 30, scheme https, host localhost, port 443 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728782 soap_transport_http: connect using cURL 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728817 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10002, value= string(59) "https://localhost:443/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl" 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728833 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=52, value= int(1) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728842 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=42, value= int(1) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728851 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=19913, value= int(1) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728859 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=13, value= int(30) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728868 soap_transport_http: set cURL SSL verify options 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728874 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=64, value= int(0) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728883 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=81, value= int(0) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728892 soap_transport_http: cURL connection set up 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728903 soap_transport_http: set header Content-Length: 591 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728910 soap_transport_http: HTTP request: POST /ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl HTTP/1.0 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728918 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Host: localhost 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728925 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728931 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728938 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: SOAPAction: "" 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728946 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Content-Length: 591 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728957 soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header Host: localhost 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728966 soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header Content-Length: 591 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728972 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10023, value= array(3) { [0]=> string(32) "User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)" [1]=> string(37) "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" [2]=> string(14) "SOAPAction: """ } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728985 soap_transport_http: set cURL HTTP headers 2017-07-20 09:33:55.728992 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=47, value= int(1) 2017-07-20 09:33:55.729001 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10015, value= string(591) "ILIASpwroot" 2017-07-20 09:33:55.729012 soap_transport_http: set cURL POST data 2017-07-20 09:33:55.729019 soap_transport_http: set cURL payload 2017-07-20 09:33:55.729028 soap_transport_http: send and receive with cURL 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774636 soap_transport_http: No cURL error, closing cURL 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774734 soap_transport_http: found proper separation of headers and document 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774754 soap_transport_http: cleaned data, stringlen: 462 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774797 soap_transport_http: No Content-Encoding header 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774811 soap_transport_http: end of send() 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774846 nusoap_client: got response, length=462 type=text/xml; charset=utf-8 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774863 nusoap_client: Entering parseResponse() for data of length 462 headers: array(6) { ["date"]=> string(29) "Thu, 20 Jul 2017 07:33:55 GMT" ["server"]=> string(47) "Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.31" ["x-powered-by"]=> string(10) "PHP/5.6.31" ["content-length"]=> string(3) "462" ["connection"]=> string(5) "close" ["content-type"]=> string(23) "text/xml; charset=utf-8" } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774900 nusoap_client: Got response encoding: utf-8 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774922 nusoap_client: Use encoding: UTF-8 when creating nusoap_parser 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774962 nusoap_parser: Charset from HTTP Content-Type matches encoding from XML declaration 2017-07-20 09:33:55.774978 nusoap_parser: Entering nusoap_parser(), length=462, encoding=UTF-8 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775096 nusoap_parser: found root struct Fault, pos 2 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775182 nusoap_parser: in buildVal() for Fault(pos 2) of type struct 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775196 nusoap_parser: in buildVal, there are children 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775218 nusoap_parser: in buildVal, adding Java Vector or generic compound type Fault 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775246 nusoap_parser: in buildVal, return: array(2) { ["faultcode"]=> &string(4) "WSDL" ["faultstring"]=> &string(206) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" " } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775288 nusoap_parser: in nusoap_parser ctor, message: array(5) { [0]=> array(9) { ["pos"]=> int(0) ["children"]=> string(2) "|1" ["cdata"]=> string(0) "" ["depth"]=> int(0) ["parent"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(8) "envelope" ["name"]=> string(8) "Envelope" ["attrs"]=> array(1) { ["xmlns:SOAP-ENV"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" } ["namespace"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" } [1]=> array(9) { ["pos"]=> int(1) ["children"]=> string(2) "|2" ["cdata"]=> string(0) "" ["depth"]=> int(1) ["parent"]=> int(0) ["status"]=> string(4) "body" ["name"]=> string(4) "Body" ["attrs"]=> array(0) { } ["namespace"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" } [2]=> array(11) { ["pos"]=> int(2) ["children"]=> string(4) "|3|4" ["cdata"]=> string(0) "" ["depth"]=> int(2) ["parent"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> string(6) "struct" ["status"]=> string(6) "method" ["name"]=> string(5) "Fault" ["attrs"]=> array(0) { } ["namespace"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ["result"]=> array(2) { ["faultcode"]=> &string(4) "WSDL" ["faultstring"]=> &string(206) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" " } } [3]=> array(10) { ["pos"]=> int(3) ["children"]=> string(0) "" ["cdata"]=> string(4) "WSDL" ["depth"]=> int(3) ["parent"]=> int(2) ["status"]=> string(6) "method" ["name"]=> string(9) "faultcode" ["attrs"]=> array(0) { } ["namespace"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ["result"]=> &string(4) "WSDL" } [4]=> array(10) { ["pos"]=> int(4) ["children"]=> string(0) "" ["cdata"]=> string(206) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" " ["depth"]=> int(3) ["parent"]=> int(2) ["status"]=> string(6) "method" ["name"]=> string(11) "faultstring" ["attrs"]=> array(0) { } ["namespace"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ["result"]=> &string(206) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" " } } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775361 nusoap_parser: parsed successfully, found root struct: 2 of name Fault 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775413 nusoap_client: sent message successfully and got a(n) array return=array(2) { ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL" ["faultstring"]=> string(206) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" " } 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775437 nusoap_client: got fault 2017-07-20 09:33:55.775452 nusoap_client: faultcode = WSDL
2017-07-20 09:33:55.775463 nusoap_client: faultstring = SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl" 
    [charencoding] => 1 
    [debugLevel] => 9 
    [XMLSchemaVersion] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema 
    [soap_defencoding] => UTF-8 
    [namespaces] => Array ( 
        [SOAP-ENV] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ [xsd] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema 
        [xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance [SOAP-ENC] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ ) 
        [usedNamespaces] => Array ( ) 
        [typemap] => Array ( [http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema] => Array (
            [string] => string
            [boolean] => boolean
            [float] => double
            [double] => double
            [decimal] => double
            [duration] =>
            [dateTime] => string
            [time] => string
            [date] => string
            [gYearMonth] =>
            [gYear] =>
            [gMonthDay] =>
            [gDay] =>
            [gMonth] =>
            [hexBinary] => string
            [base64Binary] => string
            [anyType] => string
            [anySimpleType] => string
            [normalizedString] => string
            [token] => string
            [language] =>
            [NMTOKEN] =>
            [NMTOKENS] =>
            [Name] =>
            [NCName] =>
            [ID] =>
            [IDREF] =>
            [IDREFS] =>
            [ENTITY] =>
            [ENTITIES] =>
            [integer] => integer
            [nonPositiveInteger] => integer
            [negativeInteger] => integer
            [long] => integer
            [int] => integer
            [short] => integer
            [byte] => integer
            [nonNegativeInteger] => integer
            [unsignedLong] =>
            [unsignedInt] =>
            [unsignedShort] =>
            [unsignedByte] =>
            [positiveInteger] =>
        )
        [http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema] => Array (
            [i4] =>
            [int] => integer
            [boolean] => boolean
            [string] => string
            [double] => double
            [float] => double
            [dateTime] => string
            [timeInstant] => string
            [base64Binary] => string
            [base64] => string
            [ur-type] => array
        )
        [http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema] => Array (
            [i4] =>
            [int] => integer
            [boolean] => boolean
            [string] => string
            [double] => double
            [float] => double
            [dateTime] => string
            [timeInstant] => string
            [base64Binary] => string
            [base64] => string
            [ur-type] => array
        )
        [http://soapinterop.org/xsd] => Array (
            [SOAPStruct] => struct
        )
        [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/] => Array ( [base64] => string [array] => array [Array] => array )
        [http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap] => Array ( [0] => Map ) )
        [xmlEntities] => Array (
            [quot] => "
            [amp] => &
            [lt] => <
            [gt] => >
            [apos] => '
        )
        [operation] => login
        [opData] => Array ( )
        [return] => Array (
            [faultcode] => WSDL
            [faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/nusoapserver.php?wsdl"
        )
    )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I also get this error with the SoapUI application. So I think, its not a mistake in the php code.

Answer (score 1):

Load https://localhost/ilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl and save the result in some file. Then use some XML-Validator (e.g. https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) and check if the document is valid.

The problem you describe often happens if something in the PHP-code that generates the WSDL writes output to the file, e.g. a PHP error message. This might already be visible in the file with the bare eye.

Then take appropriate action to clean up the output and get a correct WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try code below, works for me on ILIAS 5.3.8 with nusoap-0.9.5 library, iirc the one in the project didnt work for me either.

```
require_once("./nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php");

$wsdlUrl = "http://yourilias/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl";
$soapClient = new nusoap_client($wsdlUrl, true);
$login["client"] = 'client1';
$login["username"]  = "root";
$login["password"] = "rootPass";
$sessionId = $soapClient->call("login", $login); // call other soap requests using the sessiondId/sid

echo var_dump(lookupUser("John Doe"));

function lookupUser($login)
{
    global $soapClient, $sessionId;
    $user = $soapClient->call("lookupUser", array($sessionId, $login));
    if ($user != 0) {
        return $user;
    }
    return 0;
}
```